# identifier is undefined but code compiles

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a very simple program.

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include "io.h"

int main() {
    int firstNumber {readNumber()};
    int secondNumber {readNumber()};

    writeAnswer(firstNumber + secondNumber);
}
```

io.cpp:

```cpp
#include "io.h"
#include <iostream>

int readNumber()
{
    int returnValue{};
    std::cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
    std::cin >> returnValue;

    return returnValue;
}

void writeAnswer(int sum)
{
    std::cout << "The result is: " << sum;
}
```

io.h:

```cpp
#pragma once

int readNumber();
void writeAnswer(int sum);
```

First of all, the code compiles fine but Visual Studio complains in my main.cpp:
[image]

Funny thing, when I include my header file twice ... the "error" is gone:
[image]

I'm so confused why Visual Studio complains about that? What do I wrong?

Comment: IntelliSense and C++ is a notoriously unreliable combination.

Comment: _"when I include my header file twice ... the "error" is gone"_  / _"What do I wrong?"_ - You are doing nothing wrong. IntelliSense has caused many hours of confusion for people. Turn it off and your programming experience will be improved a lot.

Comment: Are you using visual studio or vs code?

Comment: Looks like vscode. Which version of visual studio or vscode are you using? Note that vscode and visual studio are different.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I use Visual Studio (2022 - 17.8.3)

Comment: @TedLyngmo - Oh, ok. Thanks. That surprises me, because my example is really simple :D

Comment: @Enki Yeah, but given the number of people asking about valid code that IntelliSense complains about, I'd say it's not a very good support tool. If you still want the help it can provide (like code completion etc.), just ignore stuff it's complaining about and leave code validation up to the compiler.

Comment: Maybe build order/pragma problem ? What if you try define/ifdef instead ?

Comment: Will the problem happen in new project?